# Extremelly high CPU usage in JSF application

Tags: java, performance, jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I wanted to ask for an advice for a possible performance improvements of a JSF based application. We are using Mojarra implementation 2.2.7. Along with it, we have Hibernate (4.2.7.Final), Spring (3.2.3.RELEASE), component library Proimefaces (4.0) and utility library Omnifaces (1.8), but they are not in the focus here. We are deploying everything on Jetty server 8.0.0.M0 for testing purpose, and on Tomcat 7,0 in production.

Our interface is relatively complex as it has many components and dialogs. We try to keep the code for all those distinct components in separate beans. We have used request scoped beans where possible, but ended up with many view scoped beans mostly for the reason we need to interact with the data inside those components and dialogs and the results of those interactions to be displayed immediately via ajax (for instance, when liking something, to update the like count; when following the person, to update the status etc.). In total, there are 25 view scoped beans used just on one page (I monitored their initialisation in a method annotated with @PostConstruct). Also, we sustained of having many Composite Components, only where necessary (around 15 of them, but several of them used multiple times).

We developed JMeter stress test to check the application performance. However, on Amazon m1.medium instance CPU load reached 100% with 4 parallel users, and some requests failed. In order to identify the problem, we profiled it locally with only one real user performing some basic application operations. Results indicate significant CPU usage on 2 methods:
- javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView (30-40%)
- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (25-30%)

Looking at the JProfiler call graph, hot spots and call tree we didn’t identify any of the custom methods that have significant influence on such CPU use.

These results were even worse at the beginning but after reading and applying some of the advices we found related to the JSF performance we managed to improve it slightly, and this was mainly as the result of changing the scopes of beans and removing some components that were not necessary.

We have also  tried with setting javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD to both 'client' and 'server', but didn't get any improvements.
This is our current web.xml: https://db.tt/Aw7L9ZYi

Comparing to CPU use, Heap use seems not to be a problem. 
To conclude with the question: is this issue related to possible bad design of our code or it is a performance issue that JSF (Mojarra implementation) has? Is the issue in having many different (view scoped) beans used on one page? Is there anything else that could affect CPU use and that we should try in order to fix the issue? I hope that somebody will have some advice, as we tried everything we could find on the web and don’t have any idea what should we do next.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure what's the idea with partialSubmit and what it will improve in our case. We are not having any databable, and most of the requests have maximum of 6-7 parameters including javax.faces.* parameters. If I understand idea with partialSubmit, it should work for those forms that have many input fields that are not necessary for processing. Though each request has javax.faces.partial.execute=@all and also perform rendering of some page area. Do you think this might affect performance and if so, how it should be improved?

Comment: My point is if you are not specifying the process tag param, then the Ajax PrimeFaces Core will process all inputs of the Form, so if your application use only 1 Form, specifing the exact region to process should improve performance, but given that you are sure that you r sending only few params, then its OK

Comment: Hardly likely that mojarra by itself is the source of such a CPU drag. Historically, memory usage has been the main cause for concern and that's in the really old days. Your *use* of mojarra, however, may be a different question altogether.

Comment: @kolossus I'm not sure what is the problem, but I found in several sources that CPU utilization used to be a problem with Mojarra, mainly because of overhead caused by state serialization/deserialization of complex component tree structure. It might be the problem here as well, as my pages are complex and have a lot of components. However, I'm not sure if the number of components can be reduced significantly. I thought that going stateless for part of the page might be helpful, but it seems that I can't make only some forms stateless, while other forms remain stateful on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add thoses params

```
<context-param>// must find the equivalent for majorra
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>  
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>// must find the equivalent for majorra
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_OLD_VIEWS_IN_SESSION_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>soft</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>    
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>       
<context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>999999</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this, but didn't have some significant improvement. Here are hot spots diagrams before https://db.tt/mD3e0edT and after this change https://db.tt/9TTh148l. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: what is the duration of 1 request in debug mode ?

Comment: CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE i am not sure if u should put true or false

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE is true or false. Duration of the requests depends on type of the requests, and is between 100ms and 1s. This is the whole list of requests I perform during the test https://db.tt/v0eFqu8h. I didn't understand what do you mean by debug mode. This responses are when PRODUCTION_MODE was set to Production.

Comment: I meant in eclipse, and to me your requests durations looks good, i dont think i can help u more than that

Comment: OP says that he's running Mojarra. Why are you providing Myfaces context params as options?

Comment: An equivalents parameters should probably exists for Majorra, and only 2 parameters are specifique to MyFaces not All

Comment: I tried with Mojarra equivalent parameters, com.sun.faces.serializeServerState=false, com.sun.faces.compressViewState=true, 
com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession=15,
com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews=15. However, it didn't help. I also tried to make some of the components stateless through the use of transient=true property.

Comment: com.sun.faces.compressViewState should be false for performance i think

Comment: may be you should consider test your app with MyFaces

Comment: you must unsure the disable of CHECK_IDS its very resourcesful task

Comment: I couldn't find any property for mojarra that disable it from checking id, like org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE is used in MyFaces. According to instructions given in this tutorial http://goo.gl/ATiXAg compressViewState should be true. Anyway, I tested both, and seems that anyway it didn't help.

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to reduce component tree with making some forms on the page stateless. I hope that might help. However, I have the problem to make only some forms on the page stateless. If I wrap one form in the <f:view transient="true"> all other forms on the page are stateless as well.